# Sending Email through gmail without need for password in C# .Net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a C# .Net code that sends email through gmail when I am using one of the gmail accounts with username and password like below:

```
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@example.com","Test12345");
        smtp.Timeout = 9000;
        smtp.Send(MMsg);
```

The code is in server, and we will be using only one email id, the email id that we will be using will be the one that is being used by one of the departments for which password we don't know but they want the user who submits the question to get the automated email from their email id. I tried like below without need of password but it didn't work:

```
       smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@example.com","");
        smtp.Timeout = 9000;
        smtp.Send(MMsg);
```

I get the below error If I use the code without password:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 

Line 120:            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@example.com", "Test12345");
Line 121:            smtp.Timeout = 9000;
Line 122:            smtp.Send(MMsg);
```

How can I make my code work that can send email from test@example.com but not requiring to pass the password in my code. Any idea?

Comment: Just *think* about the consequences if such a thing was possible.

Comment: Gmail requires a Password. Period. Other SMTPs might not, Gmail does.

Comment: Use SMTP server that doesn't require authentication. It would be a huge security hole, if GMail let you send an email from any email address

Comment: If your actual issue is to avoid having your password hardcoded in your application you should rephrase your question.

Comment: Try Gmail api. If a user allows access you get an access token which you can store and use for authentication instead. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Comment: The code is in server, and we will be using only one email id, the email id that we will be using will be the one that is being used by one of the departments for which password we don't know but they want the user who submits the question to get the automated email from their email id. I have also edited question making it clear.

Comment: Well... you may try OAuth, this will use an access token instead of the password. But forget about SMTP, you'll have to use GMail's API.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea on how you can do what you want but you probably won't like it. You could set up an SMTP server on your box and just send the emails through that. You won't need credentials at that point. But it's also not being sent through Gmail.